# How to monkeypatch Typed Arrays into ECMAScript 3 JavaScript, specifically Uint8Array? (IDE necessity in Adobe ESTK)

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript, typed-arrays, uint8array

I'm working on an Adobe ExtendScript (.jsx), which is basically a subset of the older ECMAScript 3 JavaScript standard.

In order to use open source developed code, written in JS ECMAScript 5+, I need to implement Typed Arrays, (through Monkeypatching or other technique), in order to differentiate Uint8Array from "regular" Arrays.

Comment: Ok, please post a minimal example of what you've tried and explain what's not working

Comment: There is this -> https://github.com/substack/typedarray  it says older browsers, but I've a feeling not as old as ECMAScript 3.. :(

Comment: `if (k instanceof Uint8Array) {…}`
It's mainly because it is a reworking of PostScript code, and PostScript dict keys differentiate between numbers and the string representation of a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this polyfill](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/master/typedarray.js) with ExtendScript. It does not work right out of the box though:

- You need to search and replace the variable `final` as ExtendScript thinks it's a reserved keyword. Just prepend with underscore (ie. `_final`).
- `self` given as argument to the patch must be replaced with `this`

I have done very limited test with this polyfill in ExtendScript but seem to work fairly fine for simpler things, even with the reduced performance you would otherwise would have.

It will return true for `array instanceof Uint8Array` (assuming of course `array` was declared as one).

Comment: Thx 10^6  :-)  

`instanceof Uint8Array` is the only way I need to use this (I believe)… can I comment out parts of the code to alleviate/speed up the code? Or would that break its functionality?

Comment: @DominiqueKenens no problem :), and sure, you should be able to cut out anything not uint8 ops such as pack functions, floating point etc. Of course, check for each removal that there were no dependencies on the removed function/method.